# App Config not working

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sql-server, web-config, database-connection

I have a sharepoint code, where I use connection to sql database,
when I use a string to connect it works,

```
 string connstr = "Data Source=CH-SQLD;Initial Catalog=LOGS;User ID=***;Password=***";
 DataProviderUtility.ExecuteStoredProcedureToSqlDatabase(sqlParam, StoredProcedures.CREATELOG, connstr);
```

but when I added a file app.config

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="BankGuarantee" connectionString="Data Source=CH-SQLD;Initial Catalog=BG;User ID=***;Password=***" />
    <add name="SalesReport" connectionString="Data Source=CH-SQLD;Initial Catalog=SALES;User ID=***;Password=***" " />
    <add name="Logging" connectionString="Data Source=CH-SQLD;Initial Catalog=LOGS;User ID=***;Password=***" />
    <add name="ExchangeRate" connectionString="Data Source=CH-SQLD;Initial Catalog=COMMON;User ID=***;Password=***" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

to my solution and set connectionString in it and I try to call it

```
 DataProviderUtility.ExecuteStoredProcedureToSqlDatabase(sqlParam, StoredProcedures.CREATELOG, ConnectionStringValues.LoggingConnectionString);
```

Where LoggingConnectionString is :

```
 public static string LoggingConnectionString
        {
            get
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(logging))
                {
                    logging = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[CONNECTIONKEY_LOGGING].ConnectionString;
                }

                return logging;
            }
        }
```

I know that we have posts for the same issue like 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6536715/get-connection-string-from-app-config
but it doesn't solve my problem
it throws exception :
 {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}
 In my ProjectName.dll.config I can see my connectionString